# Create Star Schema for customer transactions based on the branch, customer and account type

Tags: schema, fact

A bank management wants to analyze the customer transactions based on the branch, customer and account type. They monitor transactions using counts and amounts. Draw a star schema to satisfy their need.
In the same above scenario, it was noticed that the customer table was having a lot of redundant values in terms of the city, state and country. Modify the above schema to handle redundancy. Also mention any demerits, if any, with the same.
star schema for customer transactions based on the branch, customer and account type